# Aplicacion web con Glassfish 4.1 -. ¿Por qué los controles no se renderizan en el navegador al visitar la página?

Tags: java, java-ee, jsf

Tengo un proyecto de mantenimiento de un archivo maestro. Para este proyecto utilizo Netbeans 8.1, GlassFish 4.1, Maven y JDK 8. Mi problema se debe a  que una vez hecho el deploy de la aplicación, desde el explorer no se visualiza (render) de los objetos como caja de texto, labels y botones. No recibo ningun error o warning al momento de construir la app. Adjunto el archivo index.xhtml donde tengo el código:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Enter Customer Data</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="styles.css"/>
    <h:form id="customerForm">
        <h:messages/>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2"
                     columnClasses="rightAlign,leftAlign">
            <h:outputLabel for="firstName" value="First Name:">
            </h:outputLabel>
            <h:inputText id="firstName"
                         label="First Name"
                         value="#{customer.firstName}"
                         required="true">
                <f:validateLength minimum="2" maximum="30">
                </f:validateLength>
            </h:inputText>
            <h:outputLabel for="lastName" value="Last Name:">
            </h:outputLabel>
            <h:inputText id="lastName"
                         label="Last Name"
                         value="#{customer.lastName}"
                         required="true">
                <f:validateLength minimum="2" maximum="30">
                </f:validateLength>
            </h:inputText>
            <h:outputLabel for="email" value="Email:">
            </h:outputLabel>
            <h:inputText id="email" 
                         label="Email" 
                         value="#{customer.email}">
                <f:validateLength minimum="3" maximum="30">
                </f:validateLength>
            </h:inputText>
            <h:panelGroup></h:panelGroup>
            <h:commandButton action="confirmation" value="Save">
            </h:commandButton>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

La verdad no se que info colocar para hacer más descriptivo mi problema.

Comment: Si hay más info que puedas colocar para apoyar al análisis: tu archivo web.xml donde debes haber configurado `FacesServlet` y la url con la que intentas acceder a index.xhtml, quizás también ayudaría que indiques si tienes un archivo faces-config y su contenido.

Comment: No tengo en el proyecto ningún archivo web.xml ni faces-config. explorando las propiedades del proyecto en Used Framework : JavaServer Faces 2.2

Comment: Osea que tu pantalla aparece en blanco? si aparece el titulo *Enter Customer Data*?

Comment: asi es, simplemente el titulo y la pantalla en blanco

Comment: Ok entonces parece que es problema de la config de los faces, podrias tomar una captura de la estructura de tu proyecto y subirla a tu pregunta

Comment: jasilva, gracias por tu tiempo. Cuando ejecuto la aplicación en la barra de direccion del explorer se muestras: http://localhost:8080/CustomerData1/ le acabo de añardir http://localhost:8080/CustomerData1/faces/index-xhtml y ya cargo la pagina web. me pregunto ¿como haría para que la direccion http://localhost:8080/CustomerData1/faces/index-xhtml  aparezca en el explorer cuando le doy ejecutar?

Comment: Eso lo configuras en el archivo web.xml Si tu aplicación no tiene uno, te recomiendo que lo generes y allí configures `FacesServlet`. De preferencia, te recomiendo seguir [esta configuración](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15046855/1065197) (respuesta mía en el sitio en inglés)

Comment: Gracias Luiggi, le daré un vistazo.

Comment: Realmente no entendería como una aplicación web arrancaría sin un descriptor de despliegue, si usas Glassfish deberías poseer un `glassfish-web.xml`, de cualquier forma debes tener algo como esto en tu `web.xml` para arrancar sin colocar `/faces/...` ya que aparentemente el mapping está funcionando `<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>faces/public/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>`

Comment: @RosendoRopher una aplicación web desplegada en GlassFish **puede** arrancar sin necesidad de tener un archivo glassfish-web.xml. Lo importante es el archivo web.xml que es parte del estándar Java EE.

Comment: Cuidado al colocar la ruta de inicio de tu aplicación. Debes tener en cuenta que la ruta que coloces en `<welcome-file>` debe pertenecer a una ruta física en tu aplicación web. Por ejemplo, si tienes `<welcome-file>faces/public/index.xhtml</welcome-file>` entonces deberías tener una carpeta `faces` en la raíz, dentro de `faces` una carpeta `public` y dentro de `public` un archivo `index.xhtml`. Nuevamente, te recomiendo revisar tu configuración en web.xml. Si no posees dicho archivo aún o no sabes cómo configurarlo, por favor haznoslos saber y podremos ayudarte con ese tópico

Comment: Negativo señor Mendoza, el `faces` (o lo que sea) lo puedes colocar en el `web.xml` en la definición del `Faces Servlet` en `<url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>` y esto no corresponde a una ubicación si no aun patrón de url's con orígenes en jsf 1.x compatible aún en jsf 2.x, sería bueno ver el web.xml del señor si es que aún no resuelve su problema. Saludos!

Comment: @RosendoRopher conozco JSF porque he trabajado en varias de sus versiones, y ese `faces` corresponde a una ruta virtual que te permite JSF. Pero para el servidor de aplicaciones, la ruta inicial de la página de inicio debe ser una ruta física en el servidor. Si no me crees, puedes realizar una prueba al respecto.

Answer (score 1):

El error creo que es muy simple y es que te falta una cosita dentro del `body`, el `<f:view>`:

```
<h:body>
    <f:view>
      ---- aquí dentro todo tu formulario...
    </f:view>
</h:body>
```

Comment: Desde JSF 2.x y Facelets no es necesario, a menos que sigas trabajando con JSP (y lidiando con los miles de dolores de cabeza de esa tecnología).

Answer (score 0):

Cuando tengas problemas de este tipo, coloca también tu **faces-config.xml** si es que tienes uno. A simple vista, a mí me parece que estás accediendo con la URL incorrecta. Por defecto, JSF mapea las vistas bajo **/faces**, por lo que tu URL debería ser:

`localhost:8080//contextpath/faces/index.xhtml`